# Forcing a button to stay at the bottom of a phone screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

I have a layout that has a button I would like to always be on the bottom of the scree of my phone.  The problem is `android:layout_gravity="bottom`" only puts it at the below the rest of the layout, rather than the very bottom of the screen.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Im guessing you are using this with a listView?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, there is a simple solution: Use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and then use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute to place your button at the bottom of your screen. You will also have to use `match_parent` for both width and height of your layout. :-)

Comment: is this as simple as replace linear layout with relative_layout?

Comment: Or, better question I should say - Let's say, in a Relative Layout, I had (from top to bottom):  Image Button, ImageButton, TextView, Button - how could I go about keeping the first ImageButton at the top, the second ImageButton right below that, the text view right below that and the button at the very bottom?

Comment: You use the same parameters for each. (Whoops, forgot Enter = Save/Add Comment for me!)

Anyway, you simply start with the first ImageButton (let's call it @+id/ImageButton01) to android:layout_alignParentTop="true".  Then, for each subsequent item, you use android:layout_below=@+id/ImageButton01.  And you continue to do that for all items that you want to be below each other.  So you don't align those relative to parent, but to each other, in this case.  The final bottom button would use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" as mreichelt said.